# How to get IDD code using ip address in javascript?

Tags: javascript, localization

I want to get IDD code based on IP address using javascript,i'm able to get country code,country name,etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Geolocation API

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {} else {}
```

[Documentation for Geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation)

Or you can use a free web service http://freegeoip.net/json :

```
jQuery.ajax( { 
   url: '//freegeoip.net/json/', 
   type: 'POST', 
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(locationInfo) {
       console.log(locationInfo.country_code);
   }
} );
```

---

When you have the country code you can get the IDD. The IDD is unique, so you can declare a static object to get the correct IDD. Like :

```
var countryCode = "FR";
var idd = {
   'FR' : 33,
   'DE' : 49,
   'US' : 1,
   ...
}
console.log(idd[countryCode]); // 33
```

[Country Code list](http://www.howtocallabroad.com/codes.html)

Comment: how will i get IDD code? with the help of your example,we can get all info except IDD code.thankyou

Comment: I don't want to declare static object,i want to get it dynamically.

Comment: like how you are getting country code using webservices.